# Delayed Line Paths Animation

Tags: animation

How would I make an object follow a line path, but not right away?

For example make a character do something while standing still for a while, then make him start walking on the line path, then stop, and continue doing something else?

Whenever I use “follow path” constraint, The object changes location even if the origins of the object and the line are in the same spot. So keyframing the influence bar will move the character.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

When you create a *Follow Path* constraint, it automatically gives the curve an *Animation Generator* modifier. If you want to control this animation manually you need to delete this generator in the *Graph Editor* > properties panel (<kbd>N</kbd>). Then you'll be able to give some keyframes in the *Properties* panel > *Data* > *Path animation* > *Evaluation Time* value of your curve.

You can test: when you change the *Evaluation Time* value, it moves your object along the curve. So put your cursor where you want in the timeline, move the object where you want along the curve with this *Evaluation Time* value, then put your cursor over the *Evaluation Time* and press <kbd>i</kbd>, then create a second keyframe wherever you want on the timeline, and the object will interpolate.

[image]